# Issue in locating prometheus configuration in pod and finding the metric retention time

Tags: curl, prometheus, sysdig

I am trying to check the Prometheus configuration in one of the pods which are emitting metrics.

When I do curl to this pod using :

```
curl http://<pod-ip>:5000
```

I am able to see the metrics, but I want to view and change the metric location and retention period. But, I am unable to locate the Prometheus configuration file. I checked in /etc directory, there is no Prometheus folder. Please help me locate the file and also if I need to install any package for this.

Comment: I'm confused about what exactly you are checking. Is it some kind of Prometheus exporter, not Prometheus itself? If so, it is highly likely there is no neither metric location nor config file. You better use `netstat -ltpn` to find which process listen on `5000` port, and then check it command line to find cmd args.

Comment: @PavelSapezhka. Yes, it might be possible that Prometheus is not installed, only the exporter is present. But, the issue is I can't even execute netstat command on the metric pod because of security reasons. We have 2 pods one is a metric emitting pod and another is sysdig pod.  On the sysdig pod, netstat command works,  I checked the netstat command and grep for Prometheus as below:                                 # netstat -tulpn | grep -i prom
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9990          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      99XXX/promscrape_v2